# Sailsjs websocket not working in the call of io.socket.on()

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, sails.js, sails.io.js

My angular controller waits for the create signal of the web socket over a model to refresh the data im using on the view.
The name of the sails model is Noticia, so the identifier is noticia.

Here is my angular control

```
io.socket.on('noticia', function (msg) {

    switch(msg.verb) {

      case 'created':

      $scope.last6Items.pop();
      console.log("socket create");
      $scope.last6Items.push(msg.data);
      $scope.$apply(); 
      break;

      default: return; 
    }
});
```

Then thing is that when I create a register with a POST petition using the rest API generated by sails, the web socket is not working.

I'm using the lastest sails.io.js in my client side https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/tree/master/dist

Also my model have a connection with mysql

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are connected to the socket by calling `io.socket.get('/noticia')` before `io.socket.on(...)`.

You can check if the socket is connected with `io.socket.isConnected()`.